# "pip install email" error python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python

When I try to run `pip install email` it gives me an error like this
[image]

```
C:\Users\HARSH>pip install email
Collecting email
  Using cached email-4.0.2.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HARSH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r9nu2nma\\email\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HARSH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r9nu2nma\\email\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\HARSH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-__0a9ff4'
         cwd: C:\Users\HARSH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9nu2nma\email\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "C:\Users\HARSH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9nu2nma\email\email\parser.py", line 10, in <module>
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not install email, you should only import email as it's part of the Python standard library.

It is possible to visualize and search the Python standard library [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).

Another potential issue could be that your Python script file is called email.py.
If this is the case please try and change its name.